# Command of not equals symbol

Tags: symbols

Can you correct my mistake in the not equals code?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardnotequals=\mathcode`≠
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyenotequals}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@notequals\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@notequals}[2]{
  \raisebox{-0.05\height}{\scalebox{1.6}{\hspace{-0.1mm}$\m@th#1\standardnotequals$}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`≠ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyeconotequals
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\neq="8000 }
\makeatother
%
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[x\neq y\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You haven't said what command you used or what error you got. with lualatex you get `! Improper alphabetic constant.` because `\`\neq` is a syntax error you can only use the backtick with single letter commands, denoting the letter in the name (the definition  of the command is not used). with pdftex you get  `! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "89` because the backtick absorbed just the first byte of the UTF-8 for ≠ so the remaining bytes could not be decoded as UTF-8.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I used pdflatex. I want to redefine the equals symbol. How should i fix the code?

Comment: you can't set a mathcode for ≠ in pdftex it is not a single character token it is three representing its UTF-8 encoding E2 89 A0  really you keep distorting more and more letters or in this case non-letters, why not choose a font that you like and stick to that?

Comment: you need to remove all the mathcode and backtick lines and simply define \neq directly using the definitiion you are using for \tauyeco@notequals  but the result is not going to look nice. It will look scaled up and so  over-bold

Comment: are you the same user as [pitaya88](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/251509/pitaya88) this code comes from a series of questions from that user. If you are you can ask the stackexchange staff to [merge your accounts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)